# Add Image Upload to Woocommerce Registration Form And Display it in the Admin Backend

Tags: woocommerce

Hi I am trying to add an upload image field to the woocommerce register form and then get this to display in the admin area in the backend. I am using the code below which give the image upload on register form but having trouble trying to get it to display within the admin area.

```
//// ADD IMAGE UPLOAD TOO REGSITER
// Add enctype to form to allow file upload
function AddEnctypeCustomRegistrationForms() {
  echo 'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
add_action('woocommerce_register_form_tag','AddEnctypeCustomRegistrationForms');

// Add file input html to register form
add_action('woocommerce_register_form','AddImageField');
function AddImageField() {   
  ?>    
    <p class="form-row validate-required" id="pro_image" data-priority="">
    <label for="pro_image" class="">Upload Picture ID<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
      <input type='file' name='pro_image' accept='image/*,.pdf' required>
    </span>
    </p> 
  <?php       
}

// Validate new fields
function ValidateImageField( $errors, $username, $email ) {
  if ( isset( $_POST['pro_image'] ) && empty( $_POST['pro_image'] ) ) {
    $errors->add('pro_image_error', __( 'Please provide a valid image', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }
  return $errors;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors','ValidateImageField',10,3 );

// Save new field
function SaveImageField( $customer_id ) {
  if ( isset( $_FILES['pro_image'] ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    $attach_id= media_handle_upload('pro_image', 0 );
    if ( is_wp_error( $attach_id) ) {
      update_user_meta( $customer_id,'pro_image', $_FILES['pro_image'] . ": " . $attach_id->get_error_message() );
    } else {
      update_user_meta( $customer_id,'pro_image', $attach_id);
    }
  }
}
add_action('user_register','SaveImageField',1);
```

I have tried a few different things but not having any luck, here is one of them.

```
function add_SaveImageField( $user ) {
    ?>
        <h3><?php _e('ID','woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="SaveImageField_field"><?php _e( 'ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
                <td><input type="image" name="SaveImageField_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'pro_image', $user->ID )); ?>" class="pro_image" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_SaveImageField', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_SaveImageField', 10, 1 );
```

Any help would be much apricated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some changes to your code

```
// Save new field
function SaveImageField( $customer_id ) {
  if ( isset( $_FILES['pro_image'] ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );


    //Code changes
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array){

      if ($file == 'pro_image') {

        if (!empty($array['name'])) { 
          $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file,$new_post);
          update_user_meta( $customer_id, $file, $attach_id );
        }

      }

    }
    //End Code changes

  }
}
add_action('user_register','SaveImageField',1);

  function add_SaveImageField( $user ) {

    //Code changes
    $thumbnail_id = get_the_author_meta( 'pro_image', $user->ID );
    $image_url = '';
    if (!empty($thumbnail_id) && $thumbnail_id) {
      $image_size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
      $image_attachment_data_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, $image_size );
      $image_url = $image_attachment_data_arr[0];
    }
    //EndCode changes
 
    ?>
        <h3><?php _e('ID','woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="SaveImageField_field"><?php _e( 'ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
                <td>

                  <!--Code changes-->

                  <?php if (!empty($image_url)) { ?>
                   <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" style="width: 200px;">
                  <?php }else{ ?>
                    <h3>Image Not uploaded</h3>
                  <?php } ?>

                  <!--End Code changes-->

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_SaveImageField', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_SaveImageField', 10, 1 );
```

[image]